# Styles removed from input after applying ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a this list, and when i use ng-repeat the class not applied to the check box.

```
<li ng-repeat="country in side_bar">
     <!-- checkbox -->
     <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color: #ffffff">
           <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red">
             @{{ country.country_name }}
        </label>
      </div>
 </li>
```

The list should look like all countries check box.
Help plz.

Comment: Exactly what happening..please udpate question with more information please..

Comment: Maybe your inline style "color: #ffffff" is overriding the styles of the `flat-red` class. Post more information to reproduce your bug.

Comment: Add a Fiddle or Plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the style applied before the input is created by the ng repeat, so the new created input did not take the style.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your html is not structure correctly? The input element should have a close slash

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" />
```

Comment: I dont think that would matter.